# What is the design pattern name that used to create an object by passing an engine object

Tags: database, design-patterns

I have a class called `DatabaseModel`.

And an interface called `DatabaseEngineInterface` that have a methods such as:
insert
update
delete
select

So I can on running time determine which engine to use `mysql` or `oracle` which are a classes that implements the `DatabaseEngineInterface`

```
EngineDatabase engine = new MySQLEngine();
DatabaseModel db = new DatabaseModel(engine);
```

What is this design pattern called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, this is the **Constructor Injection** pattern (described in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG)), which is a special case of the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: What makes it a special case ?

Comment: @faressoft There are other ways to implement Strategy; e.g. with Property Injection.

Comment: is this related some how to the dependency injection pattern ?

Comment: @faressoft In my opinion, there's no such thing as *the* Dependency Injection (DI) pattern. Rather, there are various DI patterns. I cover a handful of them in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an implementation of the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)? Wikipedia states that the strategy pattern is:

```
>a software design pattern that enables an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime
```

It also says that the strategy pattern:

- defines a family of algorithms,
- encapsulates each algorithm, and
- makes the algorithms interchangeable within that family.

You are allowing the database which will be used (and so the behaviour) to be selected at run time. You have defined a family of algorithms (your interface), encapsulated each algorithm (by creating a class per provider) and they can be used interchangeably as the `DatabaseMode`l depends only on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

[DaoFactory](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) design pattern fits well for your implementation.

Interface

```
public interface DatabaseEngineInterface {
    public void insert(User user);
    public void update(User user);
    public void delete(int userId);
}
```

Class which implements the above methods:

```
public class DatabaseModel implements DatabaseEngineInterface {
    @Override
    public void delete(int userId) {
        // delete user from user table
    }

    @Override
    public User[] findAll() {
        // get a list of all users from user table
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByKey(int userId) {
        // get a user information if we supply unique userid
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(User user) {
        // insert user into user table
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        // update user information in user table
    }
}
```

Factory

```
public class DatabaseModelDAOFactory {
        public static UserDAO getUserDAO(String type) { 
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("mysql")) {
            return new UserDAOMySQLImpl();
        } else {
            return new UserDAOORACLEImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client side code:**

Then, in the client side instead of a hardcoded line like:

```
DatabaseModel userDAO=DatabaseModelDAOFactory.getUserDAODatabaseEngineInterface("jdbc");
```

You could have a properties file to be able to switch between DAOs dynamically, having retrieved that string from the properties file you can simply do:

```
DatabaseModel userDAO=DatabaseModelDAOFactory.getUserDaoDatabaseEngineInterface(myStringFromPropertiesFile);
```

myStringFromPropertiesFile would contain "mysql" or "oracle" according to the definition in your properties file.